# StartDocPrinter failing (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I'm trying to open a raw printer connection and the StartDocPrinter call is failing.  Win32Error is 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER).

This executable works fine on the same computer when run as a normal user or as administrator, but fails when run as the "local system" user.  (Though I've had it work on several other computers running as the "local system" user.)  I really don't want to consider running it as a different user, since it's running through a service and would probably involve several other large changes to the system.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EPLTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr hPrinter;
            if (!OpenPrinter("ZDesigner LP2824 Raw".Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("OpenPrinter Error:" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("hPrinter: " + hPrinter.ToString("x8"));

            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA { pDocName = "Barcode Test", pDataType = "RAW" };
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("StartDocPrinter Success");

                // Printing code omitted for brevity

                EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("StartDocPrinter Error:" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
hPrinter: 010b7e3c
StartDocPrinter Error:122
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The declaration is wrong, you have to remove SetLastError.  And not call Marshal.GetLastWin32Error.  All you know is that "it did not work".  Never, never print from a service, you cannot diagnose mishaps like this.

Comment: why service decide print something ? usually by user request - some *rpc* call. built-in windows services in this case impersonate user before do this task